# I am making a multiplayer game where timer needs to be started onStop and stopped onResume

Tags: countdowntimer, timertask

I have tried making a multiplayer game where if a user comes out of the activity , a timer starts for declaring him loser of the game in Onstop and onPause , but if he returns i want to stop timer in onResume or onPause without disturbing the flow of the game and continuing with stopping the timer and no winner declared . I have tried CountdownTimer but the problem is that it starts declared the winner but doesn't stop when i re-enter the activity . Can you please tell me an alternative solution . I have tried making it null , cancel and all other stuff it didnt work

Comment: I don't think this is nearly enough info to help you in any way.

Comment: Sir I have tried handler , timertask and countdown timer , those are already explained in staackoverflow but not the way i explained here,please give me a solution if you can